# Getting error - Update where clause based on if -else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below query to select set of record based on the `ccmflag` condition.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getdata]
    @p_ccmflag BIT = 0
AS
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.data

    IF @p_ccmflag = 1
    BEGIN
        WHERE CCMFlag = 1
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        WHERE CCMFlag != 1
    END
    ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

I am getting this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.

Comment: You can't just dump a logical flow operator, such as an `IF`,  in the middle of a statement. What you *really* have is `SELECT * FROM dbo.data; IF @p_ccmflag = 1 WHERE CCMFlat=1; ELSE ...` notice that the initial `SELECT` is terminated and then you have a random `WHERE` in the middle of an `IF`.

Comment: how about using a case in the where clause

Comment: A quick look at the documentation would have shown you what you were doing wrong, and a further look would have shown you how to correct it.

Comment: actually I was confused with how to add not equalto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier someone posted an answer, I tried that query and its working fine for me.

Query as below:

```
SELECT *
    FROM dbo.data
    WHERE COALESCE(CCMFlag,0) = @p_ccmflag
    ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```